# 2D Pytorch tensor doesn't have independent random values

Tags: python, pytorch

I've written some Python to create a pytorch tensor of random values, sampled from a Student's t distribution with 10 degrees of freedom:

```
t = torch.Tensor(())
def random_from(shape):
    return torch.distributions.StudentT(10, t.new_zeros(shape), t.new_ones(shape)).sample()
```

If `shape` is of the form $(n, m)$, all values in the resulting 2D tensor are identical. I don't understand why. I did try reading Pytorch's documentation, but I couldn't find anything that helped me understand what would be a better syntax. I suppose I could create separate samples then concatenate them, but apart from the speed implications I'd like to know where my existing syntax goes wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use the parameters "loc" and "scale" the right way. They are not suppose to be tensors. Bellow the right syntax :

```
dist = torch.distributions.StudentT(10, 0, 1)
dist = torch.distributions.StudentT(10) # 0 and 1 are the default parameters
```

Then you can sample multiple values like that :

```
t = dist.rsample(torch.Size([n,m]))
t = dist.rsample(torch.Size([n]))
```

Comment: Thanks. I think the reason I tried the syntax that I did was as a variation on the multivariate Gaussian, but your approach is very neat.